# Echo after refresh

Tags: php, echo, refresh

So I am trying to echo after I have updated the sql, and to refresh the page I use the meta http refresh, but when I then make a echo, it dissepear after a second.

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
echo "success!";
```

Is there a way of fixing this? so that when my code has done something it refreshes, then outputs the feedback so that it doesnt dissepear.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you making it reload anyway? The message should appear after you have performed the action.

Comment: The word you're looking for is `AJAX`

Comment: Because I want the value in my game to update when the button is pushed, then an feedback to the user that it has happened.

Comment: @Lars, it should anyway, the only reason if it is not is possible because your PHP calling ordering is the wrong way round.